# Can you add new CSS properties in Chrome Inspector?

Tags: css, browser, google-chrome, safari, inspector

Is it possible to add new CSS properties in the Chrome inspector? It seems that you can only edit existing properties.

Also, once you edit the properties, is there a way to view the revised CSS as a whole?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's possible to add new CSS properties in the Chrome inspector and review them in a few easy steps:

1. Right click in the element you want to change and choose "Inspect element";
2. Click the "New Style Rule" button (**1 in the image below**);
3. Google Chrome will assign a CSS matching rule which you can rename (**2 in the image below**);
4. Add your CSS rules (**2 in the image below**);
5. When you're done just check the "Computed Style" pane (**3 in the image below**).

[image: Add new CSS properties in the Chrome inspector]

Comment: little tiny thing but big help... no one notice it .. nice

Answer (score 7):

You can add new property in a rule double clicking within the rule. Also you can add a new rule from the wheel in the corner and then select "New Style Rule".

To view the whole revised document go to: `Resources > Frame > site name > Stylesheets > stylesheet-name.css`

Or simply Click the + symbol above the css properties

Comment: No "Resources" tab

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to add new CSS properties in the Chrome inspector? It
>   seems that you can only edit existing properties...

Simply double-click in any white and empty space in the "Styles" panel.

I tend to double-click to the right of the `}` for whichever CSS rule I want to edit.

> Also, once you edit the properties, is there a way to view the revised
>   CSS as a whole?

See [@Sotiris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661665/can-you-add-new-css-properties-in-chrome-inspector/6661923#6661923).

<strike>Not that I know of.</strike>

There *may* be an extension that can do this, but if one exists, it probably won't preserve the exact formatting of your original CSS.

Comment: You've probably just saved me 17 hours a year - I never thought to click the closing `}`. I tend to double click the last property and then tab to create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? Here is the screenshot of the `Styles` panel of the Google Chrome inspector [image: Google Chrome inspector]

Notice the block:

```
element.style {

}
```

You just click with mouse in that area and inspector will give you an opportunity to add new styles. If you need to add a new attribute to an element, you right click on it in the `Elements` panel and choose 'Add attribute'.

> Also, once you edit the properties, is there a way to view the revised CSS as a whole?

Doesn't `Computed Style` panel give you this information? There you can check al lthe styles applied to a node and, actually, in what rule and from what stylesheet they are applied.