# How to hide YouTube controls and play/pause button in revslider?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, revolution-slider

I currently have a YouTube video embedded in the rev slider, but all YT controls and the play/pause button are visible along with the two black bars on the both sides of the screen. I set ratio to 16:9, all settings are correct, unchecked controls and autoplay is on, but it does not make any difference. I was told to use arguments section while configuring the slider, but I just can't seem to find the right code to hide YT controls. It looks awful on the website. Please help! What code should  I use in arguments to get rid of YT controls and make the video to autopay? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by css :

Add the following CSS to the slider’s Custom CSS section.

```
.tp-video-play-button {display: none !important}
.rev_slider video {pointer-events: none;}
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately :-( Fusion slider works well with YT videos, but it loads longer and just before it loads you can see YT background :-(

Answer (score 0):

In Slider Revolution above the slide youtube layer click pen icon. Go to Settings. Turn on Hide Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Add new css rule to youtube page:

[Can you add new CSS properties in Chrome Inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661665/can-you-add-new-css-properties-in-chrome-inspector)

```
.ytp-chrome-bottom {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Someone should create an extension to toggle this. Is superuseful when you want to see something behind the controls in pause.

Answer (score -1):

Revolution slider has inbuilt setting where you can hide the controls of youtube videos you can refer the documentation [here](https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/video-layers/)